# How to make selenium python script to keep clicking a button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Objective:
Run a continuous function to keep clicking a button on target url page with wait between clicks

```py
url = "https://kingoftheclicks.com/?ref=ghost-of-a-chance"
target button = "+ Click button"
```

Later I will set it to target opponent "clicks - 1,000"
`//*[@id="__layout"]/div/main/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/text()[2]`

Need help getting this basic code to work and click button.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a@id="__layout"]/div/main/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(elem).perform()
```

Comment: what happens when you clic kthe button ?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to do an action over and over. For example, to print something 10 times:

```
for i in range(10):
    print("foo")
```

You can also use while loops, whose syntax is something like:

```
while [some_condition_is_true]:
    [do something]
```

If you need to wait between each click, you can `sleep`:

```
import time
time.sleep(0.1) #This will pause the program for 100 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need a better locator! then you should use `WebDriverWait`.

As @Kosay suggested to use `while` here is an implementation:

```
driver.get("https://kingoftheclicks.com/?ref=ghost-of-a-chance")
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.advance")))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.advance").click()
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fighter--challenger .fighter-btn")))

while driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".fighter--challenger .fighter-btn").is_displayed():
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fighter--challenger .fighter-btn").click()
```

Note: I added `WebDriverWait` so you'll need to import it too.

Here are the imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```